# Is it possible to share GSM or 3G or 2G connection?

Tags: calls, tethering, gsm

As I know that Android phones can share WiFi by using tethering. So, may I know if it is possible to even share my phone GSM/3G/2G connection? (of course without applying another SIM card for another phone.)

Suppose there are two friends - Jack and Jill. Jack has an Android 4.2 phone while Jill has an Android 2.3 phone. Jack has a SIM card inserted into his Android phone, but Jill is currently thinking of signing a mobile plan and so her Android phone does not have a SIM card.

What happened was that Jill need to make a call to one of her relatives due to whatever reason. However, Jill does not have a mobile plan yet. The problem arrives when Jack also needs to make a phone call.

So, is it possible for Jack to tether his "mobile plan" to Jill, who does not have any mobile plan or SIM card? This means that both Jack and Jill can make calls using a single SIM card but with two different Android devices.

Comment: Looking at the existing answers, I think the question was misinterpreted as sharing "mobile data" instead of "mobile plan/GSM connection".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can share your mobile data connection (3G and 2G) using your phone hotspot.

In **Settings --> More --> Tethering and Portable Hotspot --> Portable Wi-Fi hotspot**

You can set your SSID, Security, and Password in **Set up WiFi hotspot**.

Now on another Android device, you can connect to this WiFi hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Of course in Wi-Fi hotspot that's what you do. Quite obvious as the other person is already having a SIM then why would you want a new SIM to make it complicated

1. You are indirectly sharing your 2G/3G (should be 3G Compatible and
   the service should be available in your area)/4G (In some countries)
   through the Wi-Fi hotspot.
2. In Wi-Fi hotspot first your switch On your mobile data then your Wi-Fi
   after which under your Wi-Fi settings u may have an option for Wi-Fi
   Hotspot.
3. Using this your device will search for the available Wi-Fi networks
   and will notify you for the available Wi-Fi nearby.
4. When you enter some code (for secure reasons you may not want to share Wi-Fi with all the people around you so the phone asks for a pass code) the other person should also enter the same code for receiving the data.

After which you and your other person can have data connection on both phones.

**Note:** Not all the devices support Wi-Fi hotspot. Please refer you handset manual if the option is available or not.